# Jar File for com.ibm.wsspi.resource

Tags: jar, websphere

Can you please the **jar** file name (preferably file location as well) for the Package com.ibm.wsspi.resource

Here is the package definition:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.liberty.doc/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.spi.containerServices_1.1.0-javadoc/index.html?overview-summary.html

Comment: I don't understand. What's the question here?

Comment: In Eclipse with WDT installed - Ctrl+Shift+T and type any class from that package - it will give you path - WAS_HOME\plugins\com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Liberty profile, this class is available for compilation in `wlp/dev/spi/ibm/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.spi.containerServices_x.jar`.

Comment: Thanks.  I got the file now.